# mongodb querying the object, but receiving only necessary fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
//cat
app.get('/cats', function(req, res) {
  if(!req.session.username) { return res.redirect('/login') }

  userModel.findOne({
    username: req.session.username
  }).then(
    (user) => {
      var newCatArray = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < user.categoryLinks.length; i++){
        newCatArray.push({label: user.categoryLinks[i].label, link: user.categoryLinks[i].link, productLength: user.categoryLinks[i].productLength})
      }
      res.render('cats', {categoryLinks: newCatArray});
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error.code + " error: " + error);
    }
  );
});
```

I have this basic express function which queries mongodb database. It all works fine, yet I want it to be more efficient. it finds the `user` object which is very big, and looks like this

```
{
   "email"    : "something",
   "username" : "something",
   "password" : "something",
   "categoryLinks" : [   // an array of objects
     {label, "label", link: "link", productLength: len, links: []}, //links is an array of many objects
     ..,
     ..,
    ]
}
```

So I only want to display the `label`, `link` and `productLength`... yet the database responds the server with all the `categoryLinks[i].links` object as well. This doesn't change any end behaviour for the client but I want the server to get loaded with less data.

Is it possible on mongodb that I only match and request specific keys of an object, instead of all, since some keys can be very big in size.. (Another ex: a list of big data with the name of the list, but I only want the db to give me the name for network performance.)

For my purpose above, I create a new array and push only the contents I want to be displayed, but of course I would rather have the database only return the necessary info.. maybe with `$match`, but if so how will that even filter necessary data ?

Comment: Did you try using Projection in find function. Something like findOne({username: req.session.username}, {categoryLinks.label:1, categoryLinks.productLength:1}) or you want  some links as well but specific links not all ? Then try using $elemMatch

Answer (score 2):

You can limit what the db sends you back by including something like,

```
userModel.findOne({ username: req.session.username },
    { 'categoryLinks.label': 1,
    'categoryLinks.link': 1,
    'categoryLinks.productLength': 1,
    _id: 0}
)
```

here 1's and 0's are respectively used to include and exclude fields from the query.

Read more about projection over [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)